# Modify vector3 axis in list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a bunch of walkers instead of one for my drunkard walk algorithm and came across a problem.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class tw : MonoBehaviour
{
List<Vector3> walkers;
Vector3 walker;
void Start()
{
    walker = new Vector3(5, 0, 5);

    walkers = new List<Vector3>();
    walkers.Add(new Vector3(5,0,5));

    walker.z += 10;
    walkers[0].z += 10;
}
```

}

Why `walker.z += 10;` works but not `walkers[0].z += 10;` ?

how can i make it work?

Comment: Can you show what you are expecting and what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why walker.z += 10; works but not walkers[0].z += 10;

because [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) is not a `class` but a **[`struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct)**!

So while `walker` directly holds a `struct` the access in `walkers[0]` actually returns a new copy of that `Vector3` so you can't directly change its components' values.

You rather either have to store the `struct` in a variable/field before you can alter its components' values like this

```
var vector = walkers[0];
vector.z += 10;
walkers[0] = vector;
```

or you could instead simply add a full `Vector3` to it like

```
walkers[0] += Vector3.forward * 10;
// equivalent to
walkers[0] += new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * 10;
```

Comment: Why it return unwritable vector3 by calling it like that ? Using temp variable seems like an unnecessary hassle

Comment: @LuckyPotatoe as said because it is a `struct` type. This is how c# works. You will note that behaviour for every `struct` type not only `Vector3`

Comment: What about vector3 in a struct ? I've created a new struct for the walker that have vector3 in it. I have created the property for the vector3 but it can't be set by "new vector3" like in your answer